# Dotnet EF Core 7 - how to properly synchronize many-to-many relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 7 and I have created many-to-many relation between 2 objects - Invoices (InvoiceEntity) and Subjects (SubjectEntity).

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceEntity>()
                .HasMany(left => left.Subjects)
                .WithMany(right => right.Invoices)
                .UsingEntity(join => join.ToTable("InvoiceSubjects"));
```

Now I am trying to make a function that will detach all connected Subjects from one specific Invoice and attach subjects from the function parameter, but I am getting error `The instance of entity type 'SubjectEntity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 2}' is already being tracked.`

```cs
private async Task<bool> SynchronizeInvoiceSubjects(int invoiceId, List<SubjectEntity> subjects) {
    var invoice = await dbContext.Invoices
        .Include(p => p.Subjects)
        .Where(p => p.Id == invoiceId)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    
    invoice.Subjects.Clear();
    dbContext.Invoices.Update(invoice);
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    
    invoice.Subjects = subjects;
    dbContext.Invoices.Update(invoice);
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    
    return true;
}
```

I am sorry if this is already asked question, but none of the solutions for this error worked for me. I understand why this error occures, because it happens only when the new Subject was already attached to the Invoice, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Please show how the `subjects` collection is gathered or constructed.

Comment: It looks to me like you don't need any of your two calls to `dbContext.Invoices.Update(invoice);`?.. You're getting your `invoice` entity from the database already and you're not using `AsNoTracking`, so your entity stays tracked by the EF and any changes you make to it are reflected on the database already when you run `await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();` If you're calling `dbContext.Invoices.Update(invoice);`, you're actually trying to tell the EF to attach your entity _once again_ and thus you get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `Update` on invoice since it's already being tracked - you retrieve it from context just before your operations.

If you don't need to update subjects in this piece of logic, but just assign to invoice, then you can use `AsNoTracking` when retrieving subjects.

Comment: You are right, I don't need to call an `Update` function. I had also made a mistake in another part of my code, where I was creating new subjects instead of fetching them from the database, like `await dbContext.Subjects.Where(p => ids.Contains(p.Id)).ToListAsync()`.